# Powershell query to find the total disk usage

Tags: powershell, wmi, diskspace

I am trying to find a powershell (or WMI) query to find the sum of disk space utilization in a PC. I have the following query...
[image]

But as you can see in the image, it is showing separate rows for each drive.
How Can I get the total of disk space.

Sebastian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Measure-Object` should do that work for you nicely. You didnt say what data you were looking for exactly so this would give both sums of `FreeSpace` and `Size`.

```
Get-WmiObject -class win32_logicaldisk | Measure-Object -Sum freespace,size
-or-
Get-WmiObject -class win32_logicaldisk | Measure-Object -Sum size
```

You need to extract the sum from that for it to be useful.

Comment: If I could get a WMI query for this, I could use it in non-powershell PC...!

Comment: This is PowerShell code so it will only work in PowerShell. Other langauges can do WMI queries like VBScript. @SebastianXavier